# Adding label to multiple markers in google map api

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps, flask, google-maps-api-3

I have multiple longitude, latitude information in `stores[][5]` and `stores[][6]` which were passed from python to javascript, and corresponding label information to that longitude/latitude in `stores[][1]`. To show multiple markers that have their own label, I looped the code as below. It successfully showed multiple markers, but only one marker had a label.

```
    function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: uluru
    });


    {% for store in stores %}
    var contentString = '{{store[1]}}';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
    });
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: {{store[5]}}, lng: {{store[6]}}}, 
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    count = count + 1;
    {% endfor %}
```

As I found it surprising from the start that the same name variable `marker` can show multiple markers, I tried indexing `marker` and `infowindow` with increasing `i` as in

```
    marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({...
    ...
    var infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({...
```

but in that case, only one marker was shown and no `infowindow` appeared. This is code between `<script>` tag in a html file and I'm using jinja2 template in case it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in google maps api works in a different way and you can't simply loop them through without `closures` and expect them to work properly. Each marker needs to be created in it's of closure. You just need to loop through your array and call `createMarkers` function. Check the code below

```
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };
  var uluru2 = {
    lat: -26.363,
    lng: 139.044
  };
  var contentString = '<div id="content">1</div>';
  var contentString2 = '<div id="content">2</div>';
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });
  createMarkers(map, uluru, contentString);
  createMarkers(map, uluru2, contentString2);
}

function createMarkers(map, coords, CS) {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: CS
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coords,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

}
```